# How do I shrink bootstrap cards? (horizontol scroll bar shows up)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, flask, bootstrap-4

I am trying to shrink these bootstrap cards a little bit so there isn't any horizontal scroll bar showing up, I can't seem to figure out how to shrink it. I'd appreciate some help.

[Horizontal Scroll Bar Shows Up because cards too big](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZXyh2.jpg)

**The HTML Code**

```
<div class="card bg-dark text-light" id="card-1" style="width: 18rem;">
  <img class="card-img-top" src="static\random_pics\card_1.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
  <div class="card-body">
    <p class="card-text">I have been learning how to program for the past 2 months now. It has been really fun so far
            and I do not plan on stopping anytime soon. I have learned Python, HTML, CSS and Javascript so far and I plan
            on learning more about different frameworks, such as Django and React JS.</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="card bg-dark text-light shadow-lg" id="card-2" style="width: 18rem;">
  <img class="card-img-top" src="static\random_pics\card_3.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
    <div class="card-body">
    <p class="card-text">My education hasn't always been my top priority and seeing everything going around in the world
                        It is crucial that I get a proper education, whether it be programming or anything that might
                        benefit me in the future, just because I took the time to learn it.</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="card bg-dark text-light shadow-lg" id="card-3" style="width: 18rem;">
  <img class="card-img-top" src="static\random_pics\card_2.png" alt="Card image cap">
  <div class="card-body">
    <p class="card-text">I have a lot of hobbies, some of the things I love doing are playing video games, cooking and
            ofcourse, coding! I also love powerlifting, My max lifts (deadlift, squat, bench) totaled to 790 pounds.</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="card bg-dark text-light shadow-lg" id="card-4" style="width: 18rem;">
  <img class="card-img-top" src="static\random_pics\card_4.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
    <div class="card-body">
    <p class="card-text">My goals right now is to get better at programming. I find back-end development more fun but
    I also think front-end is decently entertaining for me. In the future, I see myself being a full stack
    web developer.</p>
    </div>
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: take off the explicit width and put them into columns...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using Bootstrap, you could make use of their already powerful Grid system. Read more about Bootstrap Grid (rows and cols) [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/).

An Example of how your grid system could be:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 card bg-dark text-light" id="card-1">
        <img class="card-img-top" src="https://i.guim.co.uk/img/media/7a633730f5f90db3c12f6efc954a2d5b475c3d4a/0_138_5544_3327/master/5544.jpg?width=1200&height=1200&quality=85&auto=format&fit=crop&s=27c09d27ccbd139fd0f7d1cef8f7d41d" alt="Cat">
        <div class="card-body">
            <p class="card-text">
                I have been learning how to program for the past 2 months now. It has been really fun so far
                and I do not plan on stopping anytime soon. I have learned Python, HTML, CSS and Javascript so far and I plan
                on learning more about different frameworks, such as Django and React JS.
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 card bg-dark text-light shadow-lg" id="card-2">
        <img class="card-img-top" src="https://i.guim.co.uk/img/media/7a633730f5f90db3c12f6efc954a2d5b475c3d4a/0_138_5544_3327/master/5544.jpg?width=1200&height=1200&quality=85&auto=format&fit=crop&s=27c09d27ccbd139fd0f7d1cef8f7d41d" alt="Cat">
        <div class="card-body">
             <p class="card-text">
                My education hasn't always been my top priority and seeing everything going around in the world
                It is crucial that I get a proper education, whether it be programming or anything that might
                benefit me in the future, just because I took the time to learn it.
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 card bg-dark text-light shadow-lg" id="card-3">
        <img class="card-img-top" src="https://i.guim.co.uk/img/media/7a633730f5f90db3c12f6efc954a2d5b475c3d4a/0_138_5544_3327/master/5544.jpg?width=1200&height=1200&quality=85&auto=format&fit=crop&s=27c09d27ccbd139fd0f7d1cef8f7d41d" alt="Cat">
        <div class="card-body">
            <p class="card-text">
                My goals right now is to get better at programming. I find back-end development more fun but
                I also think front-end is decently entertaining for me. In the future, I see myself being a full stack
                web developer.
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Runable Code Snippet Example:

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-md-4 card bg-dark text-light" id="card-1">
  <img class="card-img-top" src="https://i.guim.co.uk/img/media/7a633730f5f90db3c12f6efc954a2d5b475c3d4a/0_138_5544_3327/master/5544.jpg?width=1200&height=1200&quality=85&auto=format&fit=crop&s=27c09d27ccbd139fd0f7d1cef8f7d41d" alt="Cat">
  <div class="card-body">
   <p class="card-text">
    I have been learning how to program for the past 2 months now. It has been really fun so far
    and I do not plan on stopping anytime soon. I have learned Python, HTML, CSS and Javascript so far and I plan
    on learning more about different frameworks, such as Django and React JS.
   </p>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="col-md-4 card bg-dark text-light shadow-lg" id="card-2">
  <img class="card-img-top" src="https://i.guim.co.uk/img/media/7a633730f5f90db3c12f6efc954a2d5b475c3d4a/0_138_5544_3327/master/5544.jpg?width=1200&height=1200&quality=85&auto=format&fit=crop&s=27c09d27ccbd139fd0f7d1cef8f7d41d" alt="Cat">
  <div class="card-body">
    <p class="card-text">
    My education hasn't always been my top priority and seeing everything going around in the world
                It is crucial that I get a proper education, whether it be programming or anything that might
                benefit me in the future, just because I took the time to learn it.
   </p>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="col-md-4 card bg-dark text-light shadow-lg" id="card-3">
  <img class="card-img-top" src="https://i.guim.co.uk/img/media/7a633730f5f90db3c12f6efc954a2d5b475c3d4a/0_138_5544_3327/master/5544.jpg?width=1200&height=1200&quality=85&auto=format&fit=crop&s=27c09d27ccbd139fd0f7d1cef8f7d41d" alt="Cat">
  <div class="card-body">
   <p class="card-text">
    My goals right now is to get better at programming. I find back-end development more fun but
    I also think front-end is decently entertaining for me. In the future, I see myself being a full stack
    web developer.
   </p>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

You can view it in Full screen by clicking *"Full Page"* for desktop view, else you will be seeing the responsive layout.

Code pen Example [here](https://codepen.io/mbacode/pen/NWxxzXg).

You can also set the overflow property to be hidden via CSS, example:

```
body{
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```